# PHP curl - been getting spammed with these warnings recently, out of nowhere

Tags: php

```
private function _curl($url, $values)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($values),
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        //CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false //for dev
    );

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    $rep = curl_exec($curl);

    parse_str($rep, $response);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
}
```

So that's the code I'm using, and I keep getting these warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt_array(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments
```

This code has been working fine for **years** and is only suddenly causing issues.

I would just pass those parameters, but I'm wondering why this suddenly isn't working, and it used to work correctly? And is there a way to get around this without passing the parameters? I also can't seem to find any documentation anywhere saying these parameters are needed...

Comment: The PHP version or settings on your server have changed.  Use phpinfo to find your version, use php.net to find the modern requirements for cURL

Comment: The warning says that the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` argument must be an object or an array, but you're passing a string. Have you tried using an array instead? e.g. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Accept: text/html...")`

Comment: @DaveS that's the problem, I can't seem to find any documentation on this, anywhere. Not sure if I just don't know where to look for, or if there really isn't any.

Comment: @millinon wow, that actually worked. Turns out I completely misunderstood the warning. I thought the warning meant that my array needs to contain those parameters, rather than realising those parameters need to have arrays as values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found the warning ambiguous too. But yes, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER has to be an array. You can see in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  section of http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php - it's grouped with other options that need to be an array. Can't find when this was introduced though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the fact that CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER needs to be an array, as follows:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => Array("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
```